# Authentication Required on http://

Tags: hosting, whm, whmcs

Im running website thepremieremedia.com (cPanel/WHM) which is linked with WHMCS ... but got compromised and if i open i get the following error

### Authentication required

A username and password are being requested by http://www.thepremieremedia.com. The site says: "www.thepremieremedia.com"

---

Host told me your WHMCS was not up to date so your complete site was compromised because of WHMCS...

You can see live here: http://www.thepremieremedia.com/

How to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have it up again? Since you're on cPanel I'll assume Apache so that message could come from a modified .htaccess file.  Look for .htaccess in the root directory and open in a text editor. Look for code that looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "something"
AuthUserFile /home/html/.htpasswd  <--likely your docroot
require valid-user
```

Remove those and restart the service.